# Can I use react native for developing only desktop app(windows + macos)?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Helo, I am new in making desktop application and I need some help. I need to make a desktop app using React library. Can I use React native for that? I don't need to make an app for mobile devices, only desktop version.

If React native is a bad choice, please tell me why. And what should I try instead of react native?

But if it's ok, сould you give me sources for learning react native development besides the official documentation?

Comment: There is a React native extension for Win and mac - https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a regular react app and then transform it to a desktop with [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/), check out [this article](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/desktop-application-with-react/).

Another solution, if you're working on a large-scale enterprise application, is to create your own react renderer (like react-dom or react native) that will take the react components tree and will renderer them to a native desktop application.